# How do you use the contents of a Racket submodule, which uses definitions from the defining module, in the defining module?

Tags: module, racket, require

I need to require a module that horribly pollutes the namespace, and I'd rather not use `prefix-in` because it makes the code that uses it really ghastly, so I decided to try to move the code that uses this module into a submodule.

However, I can't seem to get the functions defined in that module out, while getting their dependencies *in*.

Here is what I've tried, with the corresponding errors I get:

```
#lang racket
(define foo 3)
(module mod1 racket/base
  (provide bar1)
  (require pollute)
  (define bar1 (+ 1 foo)))
(require 'mod1)
(define (biz1 e) (+ e bar1))

; foo: unbound identifier
```

Second attempt:

```
#lang racket
(define foo 3)
(module+ mod2 #f
  (provide bar2)
  (require pollute)
  (define bar2 (+ 2 foo)))
(define (biz2 e) (+ e bar2))

; bar2: unbound identifier
```

Third attempt:

```
#lang racket
(define foo 3)
(module+ mod3 #f
  (provide bar3)
  (require pollute)
  (define bar3 (+ 3 foo)))
(require 'mod3)
(define (biz3 e) (+ e bar3))

; require: unknown module
;   module name: 'mod3
```

Fourth attempt:

```
#lang racket
(define foo 3)
(module+ main
  (provide bar4)
  (require pollute)
  (define bar4 (+ 4 foo)))
(define (biz4 e) (+ e bar4))

; bar4: unbound identifier
```

Is this possible? Am I doing something simple wrong?  Do I need to fall back on using `prefix-in`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two [types of submodules](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28tech._submodule%29); those created with [`module`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._module%29%29) that can be imported into the containing module with `(require (submod "." foo))` or `(require 'foo)` but don't have access to the containing module's environment, and those created with [`module*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._module%2A%29%29), which can see the containing module's environment, but whose `provide`d identifiers can't be exported *to* the containing module. There's no type of submodule that goes both ways;  Racket doesn't support circular dependencies.

In addition to `prefix-in`, you might investigate [`only-in`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._module%29%29) to get just the identifiers from `pollute` that you need instead of everything.

Or you can create a submodule with the things used both by `mod1` submodule and the top level module, and `require` it in both:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(module foo-wrapper racket/base
  (provide foo)
  (define foo 3))

(module mod1 racket/base
  (provide bar1)
  (require pollute (submod ".." foo-wrapper))
  (define bar1 (+ 1 foo)))

(require 'foo-wrapper 'mod1)
(define (biz1 e) (+ e bar1))
(println (biz1 foo)) ; 7
```

Comment: Your snippet there was *precisely* what I was looking for!  Thank you so much.